# Entity Framework 6 Database-First and Foriegn Key Naming Conventions

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-6

We've started using EF6 as part of rewriting our application suite. There are many perfectly reasonable tables in the existing suite and we're reusing them using a database-first approach.  My problem is that EF6 seems to be enforcing what I think are code-first conventions on my database-first model.

Consider this minimal example with two tables defined thusly and appropriately populated with a few rows:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Table1] (
[Id] INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
[Table2Reference] INT NOT NULL REFERENCES [dbo].[Table2](Id) )

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Table2] (
[Id] INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
[SomeColumn] NVARCHAR(25) )
```

After running Update Model From Database we get this model:

(Oops.  Not enough reputation to post images.  It's what you would imagine.)

So far so good, but when you write code to access the Table1 entity, like so...

```
var q = _context.Table1.ToList();
foreach (var item in q)
    Debug.WriteLine("{0}", item.Table2Reference);
```

... it compiles fine but will throw on the ToList() line.  This is because the SQL generated contains a request for a column that doesn't even exist:

```
SELECT 
[Extent1].[Id] AS [Id], 
[Extent1].[Table2Reference] AS [Table2Reference], 
[Extent1].[Table2_Id] AS [Table2_Id] <-- this one doesn't exist
FROM [dbo].[Table1] AS [Extent1]
```

I gather this has something to do with a code-first naming convention for foreign keys.  I know I can rename Table2's Id column to Table2Id and rename Table2Reference to Table2Id and it will work. However, this is supposed to be database-first.  Is there some way to tell EF to get out of the way and just go with what is actually in the pre-defined database?  I did discover early on that I had to turn off the name pluralizing convention, but I can't seem to identify a convention to turn off that fixes this problem.  I tried removing these:

```
modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PrimaryKeyNameForeignKeyDiscoveryConvention>();
modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<TypeNameForeignKeyDiscoveryConvention>();
modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<NavigationPropertyNameForeignKeyDiscoveryConvention>();
```

Anyway, I'm stumped.  Is there an easy workaround that doesn't involve modifying the existing database?

Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 0):

You can use data annotations attributes or fluent API to configure EF mapping to actual database tables. Here is how it can be done with attributes:

```
[Table("Table1")]
public class Table1
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int Table2Reference { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Table2Reference")]
    public Table2 Table2 { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Alex.  However, being database-first I don't think I get to annotate the template-generated entity classes.  Changes made will be overwritten next time the code is generated.  Also, it doesn't seem like I should have to.  The relationship is clearly defined in the database; I'm hoping there is something I can do to tell EF just to do it the way that is in the database.  That's kinda the point of having database-first, I thought:  To use EF with an existing unmodified database.

Comment: @Geetz Did you use EF power tools to generate those classes?

Comment: Uh, I don't think so.  I started with a database, opened a diagram, and chose update model from database.  I hadn't heard of EF power tools, but I'll check them out.  Edit:  OK, did.  Are you talking about "Reverse Engineer Code First"?  That does seem intriguing.

Comment: @Geetz Yes, about it. It should generate classes with relations.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that there is a very important piece to a database-first approach besides having an EDMX file.  That is, your connection string must contain the following section:

metadata=res://*/IPE.csdl|res://*/IPE.ssdl|res://*/IPE.msl;  (replacing IPE with the base name of your EDMX)

Otherwise, EF will be unable to locate the EDMX information in the assembly and code-first conventions can come into play.  Mostly things just work, until they don't.